# How to Validate xml against XSD in C# windows forms

Tags: c#-4.0

All the `C#` codes available over net are just for read and loading `XML` and `XSD`.

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"D:\XML\Sample.xml");
xmlDocument.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", @"D:\XML\Sample.xsd");
xmlDocument.Schemas.Compile();

ValidationEventHandler eventhandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
xmlDocument.Validate(eventhandler);

if (valid == true)
{
    label1.Text = "Xml Got Validated!!";
}

void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    valid = false;
    switch (e.Severity)
    {
        case XmlSeverityType.Error: label1.Text = "Xml Validation Failed".ToString();
            break;
        case XmlSeverityType.Warning: label1.Text = "Xml Has some warning".ToString();
            break;
    }
}
```

This actually is not validating my `XML` just reading even if I don't pass elements that are mandatory it says: *"ITS Valid"*

Comment: This m trying to do from 1 month please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I use the following and it applies validation successfully:

```
var xsd = new XmlSchemaSet();

using (var ms = new StringReader(Resources.MyXsd))
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(ms))
    {
        xsd.Add(XmlSchema.Read(reader, delegate { }));
    }
}

var document = XDocument.Parse(text);

document.Validate(
    xsd, (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
            {
                validationMessages.Add(e.Exception.Message);
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Can u pls tell me wat my xml and xsd first line tags shud be ?? Is there some compulsion tht my target namspace in xsd shud match with namespace in xml??? I have done this too still not validating. Can ny1 give me exact syntax of first line tag for both xml and xsd how it shud be'

Comment: using this, i seem to skip the validation. even running a completely diffrent xml against an xsd, i get no errors at all. any idea why that could be?